# Centering an <img> in <figure>

Tags: html, css, centering

I have a gallery page. I have tiles that are a preset width. Some images fit it exactly, others are too wide and are set to width 100%. I want to center the image in the  tile so it will have black bars on the top and bottom

**HTML:**

```
<figure class="gallery-tile">
    <img src="images/gallery/lulBBQ.JPG" class="gallery-tile-image">
    <figcaption class="gallery-tile-description">
        Sample Text.
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

**CSS:**

```
.gallery-tile{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    float:left;
    width: var(--halfwebpageWidth);
    height: 640px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: auto;
}

.gallery-tile-image{
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: var(--halfwebpageWidth);
    margin: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: can we have a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Use display:flex to align your content vertically centered

```css
.gallery-tile {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  width: var(--halfwebpageWidth);
  height: 640px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.gallery-tile-image {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: var(--halfwebpageWidth);
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<figure class="gallery-tile">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSqrfVof7CYYRtsdCu1VD4AWoPB2gs25PP5hQAuhOwhZngrOhsS" class="gallery-tile-image">
  <figcaption class="gallery-tile-description">
    Sample Text.
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set height,with and line-height properties according to your needs.

```css
figure {
width: 400px;
height: 300px;
line-height:300px;
text-align: center;
border:1px solid red;
}
figure img {
vertical-align: middle;
max-height:250px;
}
figcaption{
line-height:20px;
height:20px;
margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" alt="Trulli" style="width:100%">
  <figcaption>Fig.1 - Trulli, Puglia, Italy.</figcaption>
</figure>
```